# Shared pointer [] operator and ++ operator

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, smart-pointers

Can we use [] operator or ++ with unique pointer or shared_pointer? As we use it for raw pointer

```
int * a = new int[10];
a[0] = 2; // We can use [] operator;
```

- Is there a similar way for smart pointers?
- If it is there should when should I use this?
- If it is not there then Why?
- Is it also possible for MultiDimensional Array ?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/ Do the same for `shared_ptr`

Comment: You can use a shared_pointer on an array : `std::shared_ptr<std::array<int, 10>>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_at) and [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_at) provide `operator[]` for indexed access to the stored array. You can use them if what they're managing is array.

> `operator[]` provides access to elements of an array managed by a `unique_ptr`.

e.g.

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> a(new int[10]);
a[0] = 2; // We can use [] operator;
```

Note the index shall be less than the number of elements in the array; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Unfortunately we can't use `operator++` on them directly; that's not what [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) being supposed to do, they're usually used for managing pointers.

And I'll suggest you use `std::vector` or `std::array` if you just want an array.

Comment: It is pointer to int[] not to int as we have in case of raw pointer. Also Can we use ++ opertator with it.

Comment: @Anshuman What pointer did you mean? They provide same hehavior as raw pointers. Yes we can't use `operator++` on them directly; that's not what smart pointers being supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks, What about MultiDimensional Array

Comment: @Anshuman Basically they're same, 2-d array could still be regarded as 1-d array of something (i.e. an array). But use it with smart pointers seems confusing, you could use `std::vector` or `std::array` like `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Here is an example
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_at

```
 std::unique_ptr<int[]> fact(new int[size]);
```